# automatic bootloader without PC software

Tags: avr, bootloader

I want to design a bootloader in AVR ATMEGA16 that when we reset the AVR, it receive hex file from some PC by serial port without run a program on PC
for example when we reset the AVR, it load .hex file from certain path to Flash on serial port
does it possible? and how?
thanks

Comment: Serial port: No. Should you want to: Probably not. How will you authenticate that the hex file is the file intended and not broken? How will you "fix" the load point to a PC regardless of its media or instantiation? You could do it through a Network interface, but even through USB no PC I know of allows being used as the device target. There's no way I know of that you can use anything but a Network Shared folder to enumerate files from elsewhere. It's a security thing. And I don't really think you should want to do that at all anyway.

Comment: No, you cannot do this without cooperating software on the PC.

Answer (score 2):

Your concept makes no sense.  Of course a program needs to run on the PC in order for it to communicate over the serial port.  Whether this code is part of the operating system or something that runs in user mode doesn't change that it takes code to use the serial port.  In the former case, the "program" is just part of the operating system, but you will be stuck with whatever protocol it implements.  This likely won't be very convenient for just getting the data from a HEX file.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC is running Windows, it is possible to configure it so that it uses a serial port as a console port. See this question: [Windows serial console](https://serverfault.com/questions/554298/windows-serial-console).

Your AVR bootloader could log into this console port and then use it to read a file from the PC's filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

If the PC is running Linux and the AVR is connected to a Serial port that is set up as a console, then the AVR can send a command down the serial port to read a HEX file on the host PC. For example, if you knew the file you wanted was located at `/media/flash/avr.hex`, then your bootloader could send the command...

```
cat /media/flash/avr.hex
```

...to the serial port and then read the file back from the serial port and program into the AVR's program memory.

Comment: thanks. is it possible on windows? can you recommend some reference for this operation?

Comment: Is your goal to (1) be able to let a user download a hex file from somewhere an program it into the bootloader without needing to run an executable because, say, hey don't have permissions to run executables, or (2) be bale to have your device secretly download a new image from a Windows PC connected via serial port without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [USB keyboard and mouse](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) drivers from Arduino. They allow some models to act as a USB keyboard or mouse.

Once you are acting like a USB keyboard, you could type in Windows-R, iexplore.exe, load a website, download the new hex file and programmer as a self-extracting archive, agree to all the security prompts, and run it. Then, that software could flash the Arduino in the usual way.

It would be terrifying for the user to see it all happening though...

Edit: you said serial port. Oh dear. Never mind.